# Lexical Analysis of Python Programming Language

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, lex, lexical-analysis

Does anyone know where a FLEX or LEX specification file for Python exists? For example, this is a lex specification for the ANSI C programming language: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-1998.html

FYI, I am trying to write code highlighting into a Cocoa application. Regex won't do it because I also want grammar parsing to fold code and recognize blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lex is typically just used for tokenizing, not full parsing. Projects that use flex/lex for tokenizing typically use yacc/bison for the actual parsing.

You may want to take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), a more "modern" alternative to lexx & yacc.

The ANTLR Project has [a Github repo containing many ANTLR 4 grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) including at least [one for Python 3](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3).

Comment: So this will both scan and parse? Awesome, I've heard of this but wasn't sure of how mature it was. Besides spitting out C-Code, do you know how well it plays with Objective-C? Any option to produce diagrams (like railroad diagrams or finite state machine diagrams)?

Comment: Yes, ANTLR does both scanning and parsing. It's been a while since I last used it, but I remember liking the fact that the scanning and parsing syntaxes were extremely similar. It apparently even has explicit support for Objective-C these days (in addition to C, C++, Java, C#, and Python). I've never used it, but you might want to try ANTLRWorks (http://antlr.org/works/index.html) for diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

[grammar.txt](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html) is the official, complete Python grammar -- not directly `lex` compatible, but you should be able to massage it into a suitable form.

Comment: I have seen that but I noticed it's very different from the lex syntax I've seen. I'm not partial to flex/lex, just looking for something that works with a grammar parser. Do you have any recommendations for a lexical analyzer using that grammar file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the existing code highlighters, like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/)?

Comment: That would solve the first issue, but wouldn't help a lot with the other transformations.

Comment: Code highlighting is not enough because I need to produce output for a compatible grammar parser.